# Resuming from a timed out "aws s3api get-object" request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to download some [spacenet data](https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/spacenet/) (23 GB) via the following command:

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket spacenet-dataset --key AOI_2_Vegas/AOI_2_Vegas_Train.tar.gz --request-payer requester AOI_2_Vegas_Train.tar.gz
```

My default region is us-east-1 and I know my keys are correct because by account is being charged.

I ran this at my home (30 mbps) and it timed out after about 12 GB.

I ran this at my work (200 mbps) and it timed out after about 16 GB.

Here is the Error:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='spacenet-dataset.s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out.

Is there a way to resume an "aws s3api get-object" request that has timed out?

Comment: I don't know enough about it to get too far, but [it looks like it has a `--range` option](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html) to allow you to specify which byte range to download.  You'd have to do some client side work to figure out which bytes you need (and maybe join different file parts together?), but you may be able to use that.

Comment: this worked for me.  Had to start the download 3 times each time recalculating a new range and appending an integer increment to the file name.  Afterward it was just a matter of `cat file.tar.gz.0 file.tar.gz.1 file.tar.gz.2 > file.tar.gz`  The final tar.gz matched the md5.

Comment: Great!  Feel free to [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with details if you wish!

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe try to work with the `aws s3 cp` command. This command is more high-level and can automatically handle multipart transfer.

This command can also take few options that can be added. see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html

specially at your work you can increase `max_concurrent_requests` and `multipart_threshold` so for example, configure as follow

```
$ aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 25
$ aws configure set default.s3.multipart_threshold 128MB
$ aws configure set default.s3.multipart_chunksize 32MB
$ aws configure set default.s3.use_accelerate_endpoint true
```

and run the copy command.

Comment: I thought about that, but the "aws s3 cp" complains about unknown opitons: (i.e. --bucket, --key, and --request-payer).

Comment: you need to provider the full path of the file with `aws s3 cp s3://bucket/path/to/file`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to download a specified byte range of an object. This can be done by using the **range** flag as follows.

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket spacenet-dataset --key AOI_2_Vegas/AOI_2_Vegas_Train.tar.gz --request-payer requester --range bytes=0-99999 file_1.tar.gz
```

The command above downloads the first 100,000 bytes of the 23 GB file and writes it to `file_1.tar.gz`.

Once all `file_*.tar.gz` broken in byte ranges are downloaded they would have to be concatenated in the correct order. It can be done using the *nix `cat` command as follows.

```
cat file_1.tar.gz >> AOI_2_Vegas_Train_all.tar.gz
cat file_2.tar.gz >> AOI_2_Vegas_Train_all.tar.gz
```

Check [this out](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html) for more details.